# Range space of matrices over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: matrices

Let A and B be $m \times n$  matrices over $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $B=PAQ$ for some invertible matrices P and Q. Then can we tell that Range space of A is same as that of the range space of B when A and B are regarded as maps from $\mathbb{Z}^n \to \mathbb{Z}^m$. please help me. If it is over a field I think the range spaces are the same. I am not sure about matrices over rings.

Comment: Are $P$ and $Q$ integer matrices, and invertible over the integers? If not, you're in trouble even in the $1\times1$ case. Say $P=Q=2$, which is invertible over the reals (even over the rationals), so $B=4A$, and certainly the range spaces of $A$ and $B$ are different.

Comment: P and Q are invertible matrices over $\mathbb{Z} $ itself. What I want to conclude is that A and B have isomorphic cokernels as a mapping described above. I am not able to conclude this.

Comment: Any thoughts about the answer I posted yesterday?

Answer (score 0):

Let $$A=\pmatrix{1&0&0\cr0&0&0\cr},\quad P=\pmatrix{1&2\cr3&7\cr}$$ so $$B=PA=\pmatrix{1&0&0\cr3&0&0\cr}$$ Then $\pmatrix{1\cr3\cr}$ is in the image of $B$, but not of $A$.

I haven't used $Q$; this example shows you can just take $Q$ to be the identity.